# MySQLwokbench use [ ] to select data but no result

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using [] to select data, but no result.

**Code：**

```
select cust_contact
from Customers
where cust_contact like '[JM]%'
order by cust_contact;
```

**Problem:** I want to use '[JM]%'to select data and it should be "John ", Michael "which the first word is "J" or "M" but no result

[image: Query]

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing like and regexp?

Comment: Your query says **"Show me all the records (of values in column cust_concact) where its contents is `[JM]` + anything following that 4 characters**". Is that what you need?

Comment: @P.Salmon that's my thought too.

Comment: Can you give us a subset of data you are expecting to get returned?

Comment: @ Andrew Bone now I have edited it.

Comment: @FDavidov Yes. But I don't have any results returned .

Comment: You have misunderstood @FDavidov and like statement. I suggest you retread the manual for the like statement and alter it to check the first character for each word you wish to test